# How to say, it helps you to know me well

Tags: translation

I would like to send my certificate to someone, because I want apply for a job.
I want to say, it helps you to know me better.

How to say it politely?

Comment: I posted two proposals below. what kind of certificate is it? The proper wording may depend on what information it actually contains about you (as a person, as a professional, ...)

Answer (score 1):

This is what came to my mind first. Neither is a literal translation:

> Damit Sie sich ein Bild von mir machen können, sende ich Ihnen dieses Zertifikat / lege ich dieses Zertifikat bei.

or

> Weitere Angaben zu meiner Person finden Sie im beigeschlossenen Zertifikat.